# Problem using acmart class with smartref package

Tags: numbering, microtype, acmart

I use the smartref package.  I would like to use it together with \documentclass{acmart}, but I get an error message when I run LaTeX on the document below for the *second* time.
The error is on the line with \mycounterref{lab}:  "Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }".  When I use \documentclass{article} instead of \documentclass{acmart}, there is no problem.  The error message suggests the problem may be related to the microtype package, but I can't figure out what it means or how to get around it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{smartref}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\addtoreflist{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\label{lab}
\end{figure}

\mycounterref{lab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles` and post the package versions? I get a different error (`Incomplete \iffalse...`) with just `article` class, and packages `caption` and `smartref` (no `microtype`).

Comment: You are missing the \caption command, and the combination of smartref + caption don't like this. microtype is not relevant.